# abbrvnat without natbib package

Tags: bibliographies, citing, natbib

I need to use the `abbrvnat` style for citation without including the `natbib` package because there is incompatibility between this package and a journal class I'm using.
The problem is that when I have multiple authors, I want the citation to appear as:

> (Jones et al., 1990)

However, it is appearing as

> (Jones et al., (1990)Jones, Baker, and Williams)

I want to remove the list of authors that appears after the year and i can't use the `\citep` because it needs the `natbib` package.

Note: I'm using the following class which is used by the Natural Language Engineering Journal. The following is the bibliography part in the class.

```
%  ****************************************
%  *           BIBLIOGRAPHY               *
%  ****************************************

\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{#1}
\newenvironment{thebibliography}[1]{%
    \section*{References}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{References}
    \list{}{\labelwidth\z@ \leftmargin 1em \itemindent -1em}
    \small \parindent\z@
    \parskip\z@ \@plus .1\p@\relax
    \def\newblock{\hskip .11em \@plus .33em \@minus .07em}
    \sloppy\clubpenalty\z@ \widowpenalty\@M
    \sfcode`\.\@m\relax}
    {\endlist}

\newif\if@altcite
\def\@cite#1#2{\if@altcite #2\else (#1)\fi\global\@altcitefalse}
\def\@biblabel#1{}

\newlength{\bibhang}
\setlength{\bibhang}{2em}

\def\bibtitle{References}
\def\bibheadtitle{REFERENCES}

\def\@citex[#1]#2{\if@filesw\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\citation{#2}}\fi
  \def\@citea{}\@cite{\@for\@citeb:=#2\do
    {\@citea\def\@citea{; }\@ifundefined
       {b@\@citeb}{{\bf ?}\@warning
       {Citation `\@citeb' on page \thepage \space undefined}}%
{\csname b@\@citeb\endcsname}}}{#1}}

\def\cite{\@ifnextchar [{\@tempswatrue\global\@altcitetrue\@citex}
  {\@tempswafalse\global\@altcitefalse\@citex[]}%
}

\let\@internalcite\cite
\def\cite{\def\citename##1{##1}\@internalcite}
\def\shortcite{\def\citename##1{}\@internalcite}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Boradly, you can't use `abbrevnat` or any other `natbib`-dependent style without the `natbib` package. However, it would be easier to help with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228): in particular, which class are you using?

Comment: Following edit: the class files are available from ftp://ftp.cup.cam.ac.uk/pub/texarchive/journals/latex/nle-sty/. Taking a quick look, they are quite old and with stuff hard-coded but are also used directly for typesetting. Conclusion: you have to stick to their [instructions](ftp://ftp.cup.cam.ac.uk/pub/texarchive/journals/latex/nle-sty/nleguide.tex), which seem to assume that you will construct each `\bibitem` by hand (not using BibTeX).

Comment: It is a shame that the journal didn't update the class, I am having a lot of trouble trying to include a working *.bib file from another paper.