# shortcite and cite produce same output in nle.sty ( I cannot use natbib)

Tags: citing

My question is similar to [abbrvnat without natbib package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/195994/abbrvnat-without-natbib-package)

I see the output of cite and shortcite commands to be same. Is this a problem nle.sty ftp://ftp.cup.cam.ac.uk/pub/texarchive/journals/latex/nle-sty/
Is there a hack?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Have you tried any code before asking if it's possible? Have you any MWE?

Comment: Have you tried inserting the instruction `\RequirePackage{natbib}` *before* the `\documentclass` instruction?

Comment: Thanks TeX.SE.Solved using \protect\citename..Earlier Bib entry was like this                  \bibitem[Akmajian and Lehrer, 1976]{akm76}
Akmajian, A. and Lehrer, A. (1976) NP-like quantifiers and the
problem of determining the head of an NP. {\it Linguistic
Analysis\/} {\bf 2}: 95--313.    Now the bib entry looks like this  \bibitem[\protect\citename{Akmajian and Lehrer }1976]{akm76}
Akmajian, A. and Lehrer, A. (1976) NP-like quantifiers and the
problem of determining the head of an NP. {\it Linguistic
Analysis\/} {\bf 2}: 295--313.